# Memory leak with bounding box in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a custom hook that will track the bounding box of some animated divs, but it has a memory leak when I add my bounding box to the `useEffect` dependencies and I can't figure out how to plug the gap.

See the hook below, as well as a working example [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-wildflower-qommx?file=/src/useBoundingBoxWithListener.js:454-458)

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useBoundingBoxWithEventListeners = (ref) => {
  const [bbox, setBbox] = useState({});

  const set = useCallback(() => 
    setBbox(ref && ref.current ? ref.current.getBoundingClientRect() : {}), [ref]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    set();
    window.addEventListener('resize', set); 
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', set); 
    };
  }, [ref, set, bbox]);

  return { bbox, ref };
};

export { useBoundingBoxWithEventListeners };
```

Comment: Why do you need `bbox` in the dependency array? That seems like it'd cause an infinite loop. Does it work without it? And `ref` for that matter?

Comment: if you check out the codesandbox example you'll see the difference when using or not. Without it, the svg's that get drawn between divs won't track the refs and be drawn properly. As far as using bbox in the dep array, it doesn't have to be there if there is another way to get it to work